# Pseudo-random stack pointer under Linux?

Tags: linux, stack

I was playing around with some code when I noticed something strange:

```
[~] main% cat test.cc
#include <stdio.h>

void f()
{
    int i;
    fprintf(stderr, "&i = 0x%08X\n", (long)&i);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    f();
}
[~] main% g++ test.cc
[~] main% ./a.out
&i = 0xBFA27AB4
[~] main% ./a.out
&i = 0xBFAD7E24
[~] main% ./a.out
&i = 0xBFCA3464
[~] main% ./a.out
&i = 0xBF96C064
[~] main%
```

The odd thing to me is the variation in the address of the variable i.

My guess is that the kernel supplies different stack start addresses to try to thwart some kind of crack. What's the real reason?

Comment: @Sergei -  Forgive my ignorance, but I don't understand the reason for a bounty on this question. ASLR is well known - especially nowadays - and it is not clear to me what more needs to be said for this question. 500 point bounty also seems excessive to me for this question. What, exactly, are you looking for in an answer?

Comment: @jww I am not looking for anything new, my intention is to reward the existing answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Address space layout randomisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is used on several operating systems for precisely this reason.  Your variation in stack pointer addresses may well be caused by this - very likely to be the case on recent versions of Linux and or *BSD.  IIRC recent versions of Windows do this as well.

Comment: If you want to test with ASLR disabled, you can do that with `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` (as root, of course).

Comment: @caf: Thanks for the hint. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization